# Don't understand this string index out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, range

Objective: enter goal string; program loops trying random letters + space until goal word matches generated word.

To expedite, when the randomly generated word has a character of some index that matches the goal word, the character is appended to a list and the range start point is now the length of that "correct character" list.

However, on the 7th loop of this program there will always be a "string index out of range" error indicated at the first IF statement of the SCORE function. I don't understand how this is possible, because range stop is up-to-not-including and I am using the goal word length as my stop value.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Jupyter Notebook with Python3

```
import random

attempt_list = []


def main():
    goal_strg = 'got it'
    goal_len = len(goal_strg)
    rand_strg= ''
    gen_rand_string(goal_len)
    score(goal_strg, rand_strg)

def gen_rand_string(goal_len): #generates random string to compare
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
    rand_strg = '' 

    for i in range(goal_len):
        rand_strg = rand_strg + alphabet[random.randrange(27)]
        print (rand_strg)

    return rand_strg

def score(goal_strg, rand_strg): #compares rand str and goal str and scores
    x = 0
    x += 1

    for i in range(len(attempt_list), len(goal_strg)):
        if i <= 5 and (rand_strg[i] == goal_strg[i]):
            attempt_list.append(rand.strg[i])
            print (attempt_list)
            print ((len(attempt_list))/(len(goal_strg)))
        elif x%1000000 == 0:
            print (x)
        else: 
            continue
```

Comment: `attempt_list.append(rand.strg[i])` - should this be `attempt_list.append(rand_strg[i])`?

Comment: [catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and in the except suite inpsect/print relavent data to see what might be happening.  You are trying to use an invalid index - what is `i` how long is the string? did you remember that indices are *zero based*?

Comment: Please explain "7th loop of the program."  There are only two loops in this code and neither will increment seven times (based on the information you have provided).

Comment: I apologize. In the function "gen_rand_string", the FOR loop will print "rand_strg" as it is built. When I run it, it will print 6 lines of varying lengths (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), then on the 7th increment is when I get the error.

I am going to take the recommendations you all have given me and try to fix it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding how Python variables work:

After

```
rand_strg= ''
gen_rand_string(goal_len)
```

the variable `rand_strg` is still `''` because you didn't assign the result of `gen_rand_string()` back to it. You don't need to initialize variables in Python (so the first line above is unnecessary), but you do need to say

```
rand_strg = gen_rand_string(goal_len)
```

Simply `return`ing a local variable (that happens to be named `rand_strg` too) doesn't magically change that variable in a different scope.

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought because I was making my function call from "Main", the "gen_rand_string" would have access to the upper scope variables and when I changed their assignment down the chain, it would affect changes up the scope.